# Darksiders Warmastered Edition - can't unlock chest in Drowned Pass

Tags: darksiders

I just played the game till the end, and just noticed that there are 12 slots to enchancements and not 11 as the base game.

I also noticed a chest that probably needs to be triggered by some special interaction

> (like the break all hydrants in the first area)

in Drowned pass, right next to the anvil with the

> (Armageddon Blade piece)

, but have no idea what can trigger this chest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. Additionally, it does not contain anything of importance, just blue souls.

[Source 1](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/how-to-get-chest-in-drowned-pass-darksiders.188440955/)

[Source 2](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/darksiders/193280-chest-glitch-drowned-pass.html)